# Created azure funtionapp is linux or windows

Tags: linux, windows, azure

Have created function-app through an ARM template but do not know about its kind.

How to identify created one is whether Linux or windows?

Answer (score 1):

You could following method to detect function running on Linux or Windows.

1.Go to the function app on portal and open the Resource Explorer.

The Windows function app **kind** is `functionapp`.

[image]
While Linux function app kind is `functionapp,linux,container`.

[image]

2.Go to the function app on portal and open the Resource Explorer.

The Windows function app **siteProperties** is as below:

[image]

While Linux function app siteProperties have its docker and container name.

[image]

3.Check the App service plan's Operating System.

Comment: Hi Joey

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: But still through ARM even have used the kind as functionapp,linux,container its not working , it defaultly use functionapp as kind for the resource Microsoft.web/sites.

Comment: how do you know it default uses functionapp?

Comment: After provisioning a functionapp have checked the kind in azure portal.

Comment: Although it default use functionapp, you could also distinguish it from windows with linux,container.

Comment: {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "kind": "functionapp,linux,container"
 }           
Eventhough am passing kind as functionapp,linux,container it always takes functionapp.

Answer (score 1):

Actually have found it already we can get the functionapp kind from portal itself.[image]